# Convert all excel sheets (with formulas) to csv with top 2 rows deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert all sheets within a excel file to csv . I also need to delete the top two rows. Output file to should be saved in folder (ProductSheets) to be created within the existing original file location.

I tried below code but on running the code leaves all sheets opened individually which i have to manually close it.

```
Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim newWs As Worksheet
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook
Dim filepath As String
    For Each newWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    newWs.Copy

    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    Range("1:2").Delete

    If Len(Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ProductSheets", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    MkDir (filepath & "\ProductSheets")
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ProductSheets\" & newWs.Name & ".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next
End Sub
```

The above code leaves all sheets open individually.

The below code is added to save all cells with formula which other wise would output as ref error

```
Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
```

Comment: hi, u must close CurrentWB too. put CurrentWB.Close after Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close

Comment: you said "I tried below code but on running the code leaves all sheets opened individually which i have to manually close it." 
All sheets or all documents ?

Comment: @patel all worksheets created by the code from main workbook.

Comment: @LuisCurado thanks for your reply. Seems to work now.

Comment: @LuisCurado the code worked for most of the sheets but for eg 3 sheets out of 10 gives error as #REF! (in last few columns) in output csv. Dont know what is wrong here as it works for rest of the sheets. What can be the issue here?

Comment: @Nisit that sheets already have that error. the formula in that columns get data from  other sheets ? its not a problem from csv, but in the excel sheets

Comment: @LuisCurado yes those sheets get data from other sheets. The data also displays fine in the sheets without any error...but the csv created by running the code shows the error.
I tried saving the sheet to csv manually (using SaveAs option) and the output csv is perfect.

Comment: @nisit try whitout the .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

Comment: @LuisCurado tried without the code but yet the same issue. This issue is just with last few columns of the sheets. Starting columns are fine.

Comment: @LuisCurado the cells creating errors in csv are the cells where i have used "Name Manager" (defined names for tables). Can this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @nisit probably excel is doing a calculation before the save. Try to set the calculation to manual in the New sheet before saving the csv

Comment: @nisit u can use Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False

Answer (score 0):

The line  newWs.Copy creates a copy of the existing sheet as a new workbook. As such you don't need some of the rest of your code. I'd do it as

```
Sub ExportAsCSVs()
Dim ws as worksheet
dim wb as workbook
for each ws in worksheets
   ws.copy  'creates new workbook with one sheet
   set wb = activeworkbook 'this is the workbook created above
   wb.sheets(1).rows("1:2").delete
   wb.saveas Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ProductSheets\" & Ws.Name & ".csv", _
      FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
   wb.close false
next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your response. For your code the folder ProductSheets needs to be there and it wont run if folder does not exist. Secondly the cells with formulas does not show up values but leaves error #REF! in the output csv.

Comment: removing newws.copy makes the sheet go blank with grey screen and no cells